# how to fetch data from two different api simulations? swift

Tags: json, swift, api, uitableview

I would like to know, according to a job interview that I have been, how to fetch 2 differents API call - let say movie name and international language support API 
how to download 2 of them together to into one table view?

thank you in advance it will help me a lot

Comment: i have given answer below

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It is Simple You have to create request chain and after getting both result reload the tableview

you have create array of dictionary from both service resposnse

For example say first will return just  arrayForMovieName:["a","b","c"]

and Second will return just  arrayForLanguage:["Hindi","English","etc"]

now merge this two array into your created third array of dictionary like

```
arrForMovieWithLanguage = [[movie:"a","language":["Hindi","English"]],[movie:"b","language":["English"]]]
```

> Solution :1  Take boolean for both service like

```
var isLanguageGet:Bool = false
var isMovieGet:Bool = false
wsGetMovie()
{
  isMovieGet = true
  if isLanguageGet
  { self.tableView.reloadData() 
  }
}
wsGetLanguage()
{
  isLanguageGet = true
  if isMovieGet
  { self.tableView.reloadData() 
  }
}
```

> Solution :2  Make webservice call sync

```
wsGetMovie()
{
 wsGetLanguage()
}
wsGetLanguage()
{
self.tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

Comment: Synchronous call would be the best approach for doing this. Make first API call and on its success, make the second API call as shown in Sol2. If any of these APIs fail, you simply provide an alert of error.

Comment: Thanks For Replay

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure to wait asynchronously for another API response. i 'm just give you a idea of implementation. after that you can implement as per your requirement.

In my requirement it needs Euro price from first service. and after that another API need that euro price and will return Payment data. So, I achieve this scenario like below.

```
func getPaymentDetail(euroPrice: Double, completion: @escaping (Result<JSON>) -> Void) {
    // Call second API and return result in completion closure.
  if response.result.isSuccess {
     completion(response.result)
  }
 // For failure handle here.
}

func getPriceOfEuro(rate: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    // Here I get Euro price.
}
```

Then bind them in sequence like below.

```
getPriceOfEuro(rate: { (price) in
   self.getPaymentDetail(euroPrice: price, completion: { (result) in    
          // Take data from result and reload Table.
     })
})
```